# Generic behaviour through an abstract class

Tags: android, generics, abstract-class

I'm using GSON library to provide *to-json* and *from-json* functionalities to my models.
For instance here is what I need to do in my **Store** entity

```
    public String toJSON() {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson( this );
    }

    public static Store fromJSON( String json ) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.fromJson(json, Store.class);
    }
```

Same thing has to be done for other classes, only difference would be the return type in **fromJSON** method. 
Now I'd like to have an abstract class providing this behavior to its child. Something like the following which of course isn't correct

```
public abstract class JSONModel<T> {

    public String toJSON() {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson( this );
    }

    public static T fromJSON( String json ) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.fromJson(json, T.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, it is java and its f** pseudo generics ... you can't use `T.class` ... you need to use some hacks like super type tokens (i think Gson use 'em too - fx: TypeToken class)